# How to prevent connector from corrosion?

Tags: connector, corrosion

I have problem with my water level sensor of washing machine. Its connector corroded at its center terminal.

[image: corrosion in male terminal]

[image: corrosion in female connector]

1. Is it true that the corrosion will only occur on the terminal that have negative polarity?
2. How to prevent this corrosion?
3. Can you explain more about this?

Comment: IMHO, the corrosion is caused by the electric current. I believe there is a thing to do to prevent it.

Comment: @Leon Heller electronics as circuit diagrams and mathematics is nothing without builded real devices. Their reliability in the real environment is a key factor for the usefulness of the electronics. Maybe some day  . say 1000 years after WW3 - electronics is only an obscure cult that has survived in a few remaining holy books and which the priests desperately try to understand despite not having even the first IC, diode, capacitor etc...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The corrosion looks like a Copper Salt (Like Copper Chloride).
This type of corrosion will only happen in the presence of moisture and a DC current and generally on the negative terminal. (electrolysis)
To prevent it, you need to prevent the moisture getting to the connector.
This can be done using a plastic tube around the connector with cable ties and some desiccant.
You can clean up the damage with some emery paper and methylated spirits. Then give it a spray with a contact cleaner (or WD40) to help displace any remaining moisture.

Comment: People often use dielectric (silicone) grease.  Petroleum jelly and ordinary white grease also work however. I've had very good results using spray grease on old style unsealed automotive connectors.  It gets inside the connectors very well.